# Is a concaved corner possible with Android shape drawable?

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, shapedrawable

I created a Shape drawable for the background of a button and have convexed the corners:

```
 <corners android:radius="8dp"
```

but this got me thinking about whether it was possible to "Concave" the corners of a shape?
I have tried setting it to Minus:

```
<corners android:radius="-8dp"
```

but that did not work, so was hoping that someone may know if this is possible?

The 'look' that I would want would be something similar to this:

[image: A sample of the shape-drawable I want]

Comment: I don't know the answer but I'd suggest you create the drawables as pre-drawn image files.